# How to determine if an NVMe SSD is compatible with High Sierra?

Tags: high-sierra, ssd

I have learned that [macOS High Sierra has built-in drivers for NVMe SSD](http://www.chriswrites.com/apple-widens-high-sierra-nvme-flash-storage-support/). It's my understanding that one still cannot boot from NVMe drives in a Mac Pro, unless one takes [additional steps](https://www.reddit.com/r/macpro/comments/8plrcv/nvme_booting_now_working_on_macpro314151/).

However, I am interested in having an NVMe to store and run virtual machine images on my Mac Pro as a second drive. My primary drive is an AHCI SSD.

What features and specs should I be looking for to get the fastest most compatible NVMe SSD? Is there anything I should avoid or will most popular  NVMe SSDs work with High Sierra?